# Webscraping text using R

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

I have been trying to webscrape the text from https://www.ft.com/content/5946a17c-63bb-11ea-a6cd-df28cc3c6a68, with the code:

```
get_url <- read_html("https://www.ft.com/content/5946a17c-63bb-11ea-a6cd-df28cc3c6a68")
text_nodes <- html_nodes(get_url,"div p")  
print(text_nodes)
```

However, i get the response:

```
{xml_nodeset (3)}
[1] <p>\n\t\t\t\t\t\tGain a global perspective on the US and go beyond with c ...
[2] <p>\n\t\t\t\t<a href="/login?location=/content/5946a17c-63bb-11ea-a6cd-df ...
[3] <p class="o-header__drawer-current-edition">International Edition</p>
```

Do I need to assign indices to the list? Can anyone explain what does the above mean and how to webscrape the text from the page. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Does this answer your question?

```
   get_url <- read_html("https://www.ft.com/content/5946a17c-63bb-11ea-a6cd-df28cc3c6a68")
    text_nodes <- html_nodes(get_url,"div p")%>%      
      html_text()
    text= gsub("[\r\n\t]", "", text_nodes[1])
    print(text)
```